# split a xml line by line

Tags: xml, perl

I have a piece of xml code like below And I would read in this and split it by newline

```
<head>
        <name>states.opml</name>
        <Created>Tue, 15 Mar 2005 16:35:45 GMT</Created>
        <Modified>Thu, 14 Jul 2005 23:41:05 GMT</Modified>
        <owner>Dave Winer</owner>
        <Email>dave@scripting.com</Email>
        <expansion>1, 6, 13, 16, 18, 20</expansion>
        <vertScrollState>1</vertScrollState>
        <windowTop>106</windowTop>
        <windowLeft>106</windowLeft>
        <windowBottom>558</windowBottom>
        <windowRight>479</windowRight>
        </head>
```

my perl code:

```
my $xml=<STDIN>;
my @head=split(/\n/,$xml);
print length(@head);
#output is 1...split is not working at all
```

what i want is:
what I want is a string array like this:

```
@head={<head>,
        <name>states.opml</name>,
        <Created>Tue, 15 Mar 2005 16:35:45 GMT</Created>,
        <Modified>Thu, 14 Jul 2005 23:41:05 GMT</Modified>,
        <owner>Dave Winer</owner>,
        <Email>dave@scripting.com</Email>,
        <expansion>1, 6, 13, 16, 18, 20</expansion>,
        <vertScrollState>1</vertScrollState>,
        <windowTop>106</windowTop>,
        <windowLeft>106</windowLeft>,
        <windowBottom>558</windowBottom>,
        <windowRight>479</windowRight>,
        </head>}
```

Can some one help? I know about XML::XMLin, but not allowed to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why? If you're going to process XML, why not process it as XML, instead of turning it into a different format, for which you will have to write a parser?

Comment: @mirod is correct. This solution is incredabily fragile to changes in the source data. For example nothing in the XML specification prevents the entire XML file from appearing on a single line.....

Comment: Seems like task for some class. No practical approach, just testing basic skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the files on the site have legacy Mac OS encoding, which uses `CR` as the line separator.

The normal setting of the *input record separator* `$/` separates lines on `LF` characters, and since there are none in your file it is all read at once.

The traditional way of fixing this is to write `local $/ = "\r"`, after which file read statements in the same scope will be terminated by `CR` characters. Also `chomp` will remove a `CR` from the end of the line.

But this can be awkward if you are reading simultaneously from multiple files witrh different line terminators, as it affects the `<FH>` operator and not a specific file handle.

The neatest way I have come across to deal with this is to install the [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO%3a%3aeol) module, which lets you open *any* file with a `MODE` of `<:raw:eol(LF)`. This changes all the different line terminators to the standard `"\n"` and your program will behave as normal independently of the source of the data.

**Note** that the module only needs to be installed - there is no need for a `use` line in the program.

Comment: Thanks, now it split properly into array, but still not able to print to console `local $/ ="\r";
my @xml=<STDIN>;print @xml;
print "\n";` it gives "<opml ve</opml>2</body>e</outline>outline>ext="Texas"/>co"/>a"/>created="Tue, 12 Jul 2005 23:56:47 GMT"/>/>". So how do I print out a file encoded like that?

Comment: I still recommend useing `PerlIO::eol`, but if you insist on modifying `$/` then you will have to account for the lines in `@xml` ending in `CR` instead of `LF`. You could `chomp` them and add a `"\n"` after each line by writing `local $/ ="\r"; my @xml=<STDIN>; chomp @xml; print "$_\n" for @xml;`. But with the module all you would need is `binmode STDIN, ':raw:eol(LF)'; my @xml=<STDIN>; print @xml;`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is working as it should. You only read one line into `$xml`, so `split` only returns one line. If you were slurping the file into the scalar `$xml`, then you would need to split, and this code would work:

```
local $/ = undef;   # set input record separator to undef (instead of newline)
my $xml=<STDIN>;    # all lines are now in $xml
my @head=split(/\n/,$xml);    # so now we can split it
```

This code, however, does not do what you think:

```
print length(@head);
```

It prints the length of the size of the array, which is 1. `@head` is evaluated in scalar context as a string, and the string "1" has length 1. What you were looking for was simply:

```
print scalar @head;
```

But why go to all that trouble? Just do:

```
my @head = <STDIN>;   # all the lines are now in @head
print scalar @head;
```

If you need to remove the newlines, use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
chomp(my @head = <STDIN>);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help. I input the file by "$ ./read.pl<head.xml" and then print out the @head by a for loop. it just print out one line `foreach my $k (keys @head){
 print $head[$k]."\n";
}`

Comment: @user1391821 `keys` is not (really) for arrays, its for hashes. Though it can be used for arrays to get their indexes in recent versions of perl. You don't need to loop at all, just do `print @head`, since print can take a list as argument. If you avoid removing the newlines (with `chomp` or `split`) earlier, you'll get a nice print.

Comment: the file I use is from examples in this site http://dev.opml.org/spec2.html if I copy the xml text and save it myself the code works. if i use `save linked file as` direct download the opml file, no matter what i do it always in one line and the split not work

Comment: Then I guess there is some difference between the files. You should investigate what that difference is.